# mount paritions manually without a partition table in linux

Tags: mount, partition, loop-device

I am trying to programmatically mount partition tables in linux with a partition table.

Heres what I did so far to see if I can mount a partition in backup with a damaged drive (deleted partition table) using losetup. I am assuming that I am able to find the beginning and end sectors here.

I created a new file containing 2 partitions using

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=backup.img bs=1M count=100`

`sudo fdisk backup.img` and partitioned `backup.img` into two partitions, after which `sudo fdisk -lu backup.img` shows as follows

```
Device   Boot  Start   End   Sectors   Size Id   Type
backup.img1       2048  104447  102400    50M 83   Linux
backup.img2     104448  204799  100352    49M 83   Linux
```

The partitions here are `ext3` and `ext4` partitions as I am just testing if I can mount partitions with a non-existant partion table using `losetup`

Then I tried this

`sudo losetup -r -o 1048576 /dev/loop0 backup.img` works, after which I can do `sudo mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/test`.

However, I am assuing that I have a raw image with no partition table, so I have to manually provide the partition table. Also I dont want to mess with the existing backup as it could damage the disk further.

`sudo losetup -o 1048576 --sizelimit 52428288 /dev/loop0 backup.img` works.

However, when I try to mount the loop device using

`sudo mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/test`, it fails saying

`mount: /mnt/test: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program or other error`

Why does `losetup` not recognize the partition when I provide the sizelimit?

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Why the -o 40000 in the otherwise very sensible losetup call? Also, does `file sda2.img` agree this is a file system containing image?

Comment: thats the offset for the start of the partition of apfs

Comment: the question is when I use `losetup`, does it just try to replicate a system similar to the `/dev/sda2` when I mount the usb drive, or is it doing something different? `400000` is just approximate

Comment: "just approximate" will never do, why do you do that?. Loser up does nothing - it just takes a file (and optionally, an offset into that for) and tells the kernel "make a block device backed by this file". So, if that file contains an image of a partition with a file system on it, that can than be mounted. If not, then not. What does your sda2.img contain?

Comment: i apologize.. i just put 400000 here, that doesnt mean I am not using exact numbers when running the commands. I will edit the question above

Comment: Bit confused, a raw image of a while disk would always contain the partition table

Comment: I modified my tests.. would you mind checking the question above? I am assuming the partition table no longer exists and is damaged

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because doing brain surgery on an APFS disk is inappropriate for a Q&A site.

Comment: this is not specific for apfs. `losetup` is not working as expected on my system, so I am asking if there is any way to debug this. Check answer by @Phillip below

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yes, it would. In this case the disk is damaged, otherwise I wouldnt have to do this

Comment: @CarriMegrabyan What are you doing??? You are changing the context of this question completely! Stop editing it, please. I just read the original post and you changed, well, commands, etc.

Comment: @CarriMegrabyan As the OP (original poster) you should not edit your questions in such a major way. I see you are not new here, which is OK, no one forces you to post something every week... Just please calm down a bit with those enormous edits. Thank you!

Comment: @waltinator Please retract your close vote, it was just a mistake, this question really is not related to APFS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong in theory with the commands you are using to setup the loop device.  I use something similar in build scripts to generate images.

My guess is that you accidentally formatted your test image incorrectly, perhaps you made the ext file system larger than it should have been.

Loop devices are just block devices pointing to a section of a file and they know nothing about the partition table.  Likewise partitions are nothing more than a section on the disk with a table entry describe where on disk they are.

The easiest way to get block devices for your partitions is to use the partition table which *should* be there on any disk.

You can actually ask Linux to add loop partitions for you if the image already has a partition table:

```bash
loop_device=$(losetup --show -f my image.img)
partx -a $loop_device
```

This will create a set of devices such as `/dev/loop2` `/dev/loop2p1` `/dev/loop2p2`. This avoids you messing around with calculating offsets.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `sudo` in your `dd` command, the following is OK:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=backup.img bs=1M count=100
```

Again, to create/edit the partition table in there, you do not need `sudo`:

```
$ gdisk backup.img 
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries in memory.

Command (? for help): o
This option deletes all partitions and creates a new protective MBR.
Proceed? (Y/N): y

Command (? for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 
First sector (34-204766, default = 2048) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 
Last sector (2048-204766, default = 204766) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 102400
Current type is 8300 (Linux filesystem)
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300): 8300
Changed type of partition to 'Linux filesystem'

Command (? for help): c
Using 1
Enter name: Test_1

Command (? for help): n
Partition number (2-128, default 2):  
First sector (34-204766, default = 104448) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 
Last sector (104448-204766, default = 204766) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 
Current type is 8300 (Linux filesystem)
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300): 
Changed type of partition to 'Linux filesystem'

Command (? for help): c
Partition number (1-2): 2
Enter name: Test_2

Command (? for help): p
Disk backup.img: 204800 sectors, 100.0 MiB
Sector size (logical): 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 61A000F6-7F51-4615-B1B6-82D4C9E305B3
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 204766
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 4061 sectors (2.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          102400   49.0 MiB    8300  Test_1
   2          104448          204766   49.0 MiB    8300  Test_2

Command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to backup.img.
Warning: The kernel is still using the old partition table.
The new table will be used at the next reboot or after you
run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
The operation has completed successfully.
```

And the same goes for showing the partition table, no `sudo`:

```
$ fdisk -l backup.img 
Disk backup.img: 100 MiB, 104857600 bytes, 204800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 61A000F6-7F51-4615-B1B6-82D4C9E305B3

Device       Start    End Sectors Size Type
backup.img1   2048 102400  100353  49M Linux filesystem
backup.img2 104448 204766  100319  49M Linux filesystem
```

Now you want some file system on those partitions, ok, let me create both `ext4`, type of file system I believe does not matter at this point.

```
$ sudo kpartx -a backup.img

$ losetup --list | grep backup.img
/dev/loop19         0      0         0  0 /home/vlastimil/partition-experiments/backup.img       0     512

$ sudo mkfs.ext4 -L Test_ext4_1 -m 0 -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0 /dev/mapper/loop19p1 
mke2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Discarding device blocks: done                            
Creating filesystem with 12544 4k blocks and 12544 inodes

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (1024 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

# The same command for /dev/mapper/loop19p2
```

After that, I mean after creating an image of a disk, I mounted it always using sectors multiplied by, but as we used `kpartx` above, it simplified it to:

```
$ mkdir mntpoint
$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop19p1 mntpoint1/
$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop19p2 mntpoint2/
```

Now, you shall have both partitions mounted.

Comment: thanks for the detailed writeup. didnt try running without `sudo`, but my issue before was different. I think I solved it for now..